# How to fetch common item from two tables - Oracle

Tags: oracle, join, group-by, left-join, outer-join

Scenario - I have users who are assigned different restrictions over several items. These restrictions are specified in restriction groups. Sometimes it happens that a user is a part of more than one restriction group. Sometimes, by mistake a user is assigned those restriction groups that have a conflict restriction for a common item. For example, User 123 is a part of restriction group A1 and B1 that have a common item Green Ball wherein restriction group A1 has a restriction that User 123 can access only 3 Green Balls a day while restriction group B1 says that User 123 can access only 2 Green Balls a day, thus leading to a conflict. I have to build a query that will fetch the information in such scenarios where there is a conflict. Every user belongs to a particular region, so the results will be filtered using region ID. My query should output.

```
UserId, Common Item, Restriction Group Name, Restriction
```

Tables

```
user - Id, userregionid
userRestriction - userId, restrictionGroup
restrictions- Item, restrictionGroup, restriction, interval // For example, Green Balls, Group A1, 3 , 1 (means 1 day)
```

My Effort -

```
select user.id, 
userRestriction.restrictionGroup,
restrictions.Item,
restriction.restriction, 
restriction.interval

from user left outer join userRestriction on user.Id = userRestriction.userId

left outer join restrictions on userRestriction.restrictionGroup = restriction.restrictionGroup

where user.useregionid= '12345'

group by userRestriction.userid, 
user.id, 
userRestriction.restrictionGroup,
restrictions.Item, 
restriction.restriction,
restriction.interval,user.userregionid
having count(userRestriction.restrictiongroup)>1
```

I am getting nothing by running this query. This is not correct as I have data that should get resulted.

In my database, I have UserRestriction Table

```
UserId | RestrictionGroup

EID-999| A1
EID-888 | B1
EID-999 | C1
```

In the Restriction table

```
Item | RestrictionGroup| restriction | interval

GreenBalls| A1 | 1 | 1
Pen       | B1 |1  | 7
GreenBalls|C1  |1  |30
```

The query should output

```
EID-999 | GreenBalls | A1 | 1 | 1
EID-999 | GreenBalls | C1 | 1 |30
```

User Table :

```
Id | userregionid

EID-999 | 12345
EID- 888 | 12345
D-900 | 2322
F-999 | 6767
```

The query should fetch only those users belonging to the specified userregionid.

Comment: Please post the sample data for User table also.

Comment: The reason for blank result  might be that in User table you have Id as `E-999` while in UserRestriction you have Id as `EID-999`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I typed in the sample data for you. Updated the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some issues with your query. You can try below query -

```
select U.id,
       UR.restrictionGroup,
       R.Item,
       R.restriction,
       R.interval
  from users U
  left outer join userRestriction UR on U.Id = UR.userId
  left outer join restrictions R on UR.restrictionGroup = R.restrictionGroup
 where U.userregionid = 12345
 group by U.id,
          UR.restrictionGroup,
          R.Item,
          R.restriction,
          R.interval
having count(UR.RestrictionGroup) >= 1
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f1987834a16e0b507c0c287e260aae90)

Comment: This query is same as mine. I tried it and its not fetching anything.

Comment: I think Having clause is the main culprit there. I have updated it. Please try now and let me know the result.

Comment: I added another item ```INSERT INTO Restrictions VALUES('GreenPen', 'C1', 1, 30);``` to the table restrictions. Now, the query fetches this value also. but it should not fetch this value.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=98a4fec05b5b5cffa348980e261be80c

Comment: I updated the data, it also shows data for employee assigned D1 group. but it should not show that one. Its maybe because we are using left  outer join.

Comment: Why should the newly inserted record not come into the result?